# Hibernate @ColumnTransformer inject database schema

Tags: java, hibernate

I have issues injecting the database schema to my @ColumnTransformer, eg

```
@ColumnTransformer(
read = "(select trim(sct.CD) from {h-schema}SCT sct where sct.CD_TBL_ID = 4 and sct.CSN = KEY_VAL_TCSN)"
)
```

Does not resolve the {h-schema}, but instead it translates to

```
(select trim(sct.CD) from {h-kvlist0_.schema}VTKC028_SCT kvlist0_.sct where sct.CD_TBL_ID = 4 and sct.CSN = kvlist0_.KEY_VAL_TCSN)
```

I am trying to resolve crossreference of KEY_VAL_TCSN from SCT.CD table.

So it replaces the {h-schema} with {h-kvlist0_.schema} instead of the query schema.